# python how to convert ascii codes to original characters

Tags: python

Using python 2.7.2

I'm having issues with special characters with ascii values > 128

The problem is that our data got corrupted by iso vs utf8 convertion. so We are trying to fix this.

Where are trying to fix it using python. We loop through our data character by character fix the corrupted values. and get an ascii # code. let say I want to replace ascii code 226 with ascii code 146, which is a special quote "’":

```
c='â'
   print ord ( c ) 
   226
```

How can I decode 226 back to `â` or convert ascii 146 to "’"?

Comment: chr(226) and those quotes are 8217

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `chr` function you will want the `unichr` function:

```
 >>> c = u'â'
 >>> print(ord(c))
 226
 >>> unichr(226)
 u'\xe2'
 >>> print(unichr(226))
 â
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the chr function. Or is your problem that you don't have the right codepage?

Comment: chr () function works well for acsii code set upto 128.. how to we decode ascii code page from 128 --- 255

Comment: There is no ascii above 127. But chr still works above 127, for me (python 2, resulting in a normal string). Since you just want to safe the modified file back to disk, not print it, that should be good enough.